# Flutter 3.16.3. Error when reading '../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart': No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

in Flutter 3.16.3, I get this error when make run.

../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/cupertino.dart:50:1: Error: Error when reading '../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart': No such file or directory
export 'src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart';
^
../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/widget_tester.dart:1147:34: Error: The getter 'CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton' isn't defined for the class 'WidgetTester'.

- 'WidgetTester' is from 'package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart' ('../../../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/src/widget_tester.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton'.
  backButton = find.byType(CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/Users/mohamedkilany/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhnbn.png)
i Get this error